# koahana auth module: get unhashed user password value

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

I have a form to allow a user to edit their details however the password associated to the user model is hashed. What is the best way to unhash this so I can add it to the form?

```
// get user
$user = ORM::factory('user', $id);

// in the form
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $user->password; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't unhash a hash. That's the point of the hash. This is a bad idea. You should never repopulate or email someone their password.

Comment: If I could upvote this a million times, I would. Nothing is as irritating as receiving a plaintext password in email.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a hashed password as a one way street. It is okay to go down it one way but not the opposite way.  I also agree with zombor that this is a bad practice.